# How to delete firebase-demo-project from google developer console

Tags: firebase-console, google-developers-console

I know this question have been answered here on stack overflow, but in my case, I have a project in my google developer console named "firebase-demo-project".  In this same console, I cannot delete the project : it seems I don't have de right permission to do so (the delete options are grayed).

On the other side, in the firebase console for the same user, I have no project at all.  So I cannot just delete the project from firebase since it's not there.

Anyone can help with this ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have to enter the project name and then the delete options becomes available? :)

Comment: I don't understand where to enter that name.  When I go to project settings, it says I have no authorization to do anything (for this project) :(

Comment: could you maybe add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: The Firebase Demo Project is owned by Google and is under a Google Billing Account. All charges for this project is paid by Google.

I'm not sure based on what criteria they've added people. Might be some firebase-demo-users group or so

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its simple. Open Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com)
Click on Explore Demo Project Button
On the next page on top right click on Exit Demo.
That's all.

Now in you Cloud Console, your firebase demo will be gone. (refresh page if already open).

Comment: I did exactly this - did not help. The project remains and exhausts my quota

Answer (score 1):

Top right on the main project page there is a leave demonstration link.  It erased the project from my Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Ok I did it using the firebase console, following the instructions.  I tough I could do it in the google console but now I understand I cannot.  Thank you :)